# check instance variable value in before filter rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

In my controller I have a method which checks for next item. But before executing this method I need to set an instance variable which is written in the before_filter method. So how do I test it in rspec.

```
before_filter method check_items, :only[:next]
def check_items
    if params[:item] == "Sherlock"
      @item = $book1
    elsif params[:item] == "Harry"
      @queue = $book2
    else
      render :json=>{"Error" => "Book name does not exist"}
    end
  end
```

=======================

```
def next
   @book = @item.pull
      unless @book.nil?
      respond_with(@book)
    else
      render :json =>{"msg"=>"Nothing to pull"}
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue? If so, can you share the knowledge with us?.. Did you try the suggested answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing controller specs, you can test this behavior with `assigns` constraint. You may end up with something like this:

```
it "assigns @item" do
  item = Item.create
  get :next
  expect(assigns(:item)).to eq(item)
end
```

If you write unit tests, you can use `instance_variable_get` method. But I would avoid it - I would go with controller specs.

Hope that helps